# How to attach pdf embedded in excel in outlook email with vba

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook, attachment

I have created an embedded pdf with the insert> object > create from file> browse > display as icon function in excel.

I would like to then use the embedded pdf as an attachment for my outlook email using vba code. I have tried to use the .Attachment.Add code but it seems to fail to detech an embedded object.

Could anyone advise a correct code? Thanks!

Comment: Why do you need to embed the PDF object in the workbook, if you're going to be emailing it separately anyhow?  Also, can you not grab the actual `.PDF` for the attachment from the same location that you embedded it *from?*

Comment: also, which version of Excel are you using?

Comment: I have already built a button which could automatically generate an outlook email with the excel content as a template. I would like to include the embeded pdf in the template as well

Comment: I could not grad the attachment using the path since it is linked to sharepoint and I do not want to excel to access sharepoint everytime when creating the attachment since it would take at least 10secs to generate the email template

Answer (score 0):

### Get the file from the source?

I don't understand why you would need to embed the`.PDF` object in the workbook, if you're going to be emailing it separately anyhow...

Regardless, you could just grab the actual/original `.PDF` to attach a copy to the email, directly from the **same location** from where it was embedded.  (If it's not there, what happened to it?)

---

### Another option:

As soon as you right-click the embedded object, Excel 2016 "gets ready" for you to open it by extracting it to your local temp folder. (I'm unsure whether this applies to previous versions.)

Therefore, you could **programmatically right-click** the embedded icon, and then check the temp folder located at the path that you'll find stored in **`Environ("temp")`**.  One or more copies of your file will be located there (and it should be the 'newest' PDF).

---

### Yet another option:

Excel's XLSM file is simply a **compressed ZIP file**, if you change the extension.  You could programmatically make a copy of the file, changing it's extension to `.ZIP`.

Embedded object are stored as `.BIN` files within the ZIP file in the `xl\embeddings\` folder.  It would have to be extracted and then renamed back to a PDF.  Note that this method is a little flakey and won't work with all PDF's.

---

### More Information:

- VBA Express : [**Save embedded PDF file as a separate PDf file**](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?59478-Save-embedded-PDF-file-as-a-separate-PDf-file)
- How-to-Geek : [**How to Extract Images, Text, and Embedded Files from Office Documents**](https://www.howtogeek.com/50628/easily-extract-images-text-and-embedded-files-from-an-office-2007-document/)

Comment: I have already built a button which could automatically generate an outlook email with the excel content as a template. I would like to include the embeded pdf in the template as well.

Comment: I could not grad the attachment using the path since it is linked to sharepoint and I do not want to excel to access sharepoint everytime when creating the attachment since it would take at least 10secs to generate the email template

Comment: @vba.beginner - as I said, the copy it's making of the object's source file when you right-click the object, is **stored *locally*** (as a cache) in the local temp folder. I assume you're opening the Excel file locally as well, so by that point, there is already a locally stored copywhich means it's already made a local copy of the file.  it is, so there would be no additional SharePoint communication necessary.

Comment: May I know how can I find the path to the local temp folder then? I tried to right click but saw nothing

Comment: and does that mean I have to change the path everytime if another pdf has been used to replace the previously embedded one?